# Lenovo fingerprint sensor linux IdeaPad 3 15IAU7 Laptop - Type 82RK Not working

Tags: login, lenovo, 23.10, fingerprint-reader

Running `lsusb` gives me the model.

> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c4b Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint

When I go to

> Settings → User → Unlock user

and then enable the fingerprint login, I check the scan's new fingerprint, and I get

> fingerprint device disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

That sensor [isn't fully supported](https://github.com/iafilatov/libfprint/issues/39) but it somewhat works [if you are careful with your finger](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/285#note_1734717):

> After hundreds tries of fprintd-enroll and fprintd-verify I managed to register my fingerprints the way the scanner can recognize my fingers in about 50% attempts. It works only when I enroll my fingers in the direction from screen to keyboard. Any angle leads to failing verification. The enrolling speed is like within one second. Sometimes the led left to the scanner blinks, sometimes it just constantly on. It seems like in both led states the sensor works the same way, recognition quality is not being increased or decreased. But I'm not sure.
> Anyway, this is not normal work.
> Idk, if this information helps to anybody, but I just left it here.

Comment: But it doesnt give me an option. It set the fingerprint device disconnected from start. I cannot try to set a fingerprint

Comment: @panOS Have you tried using `fprintd-enroll`?

Comment: I was trying from GUI, you are right. WIth terminal I managed with your technic to pass it. But nevertheless even though Its now registered I cant login with it. I tap my finger. I dont get an error, it just reshowing the user login